# RadioSelect widget does not show labels in MultiWidget

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to build a custom MultiValue field in django that consists of two widgets: RadioSelect and TextInput: if a user chooses 'Other' then they can insert the value there.

Everything works, with one weird exception: the labels for radio buttons are not shown (see picture). Values are rendered ok, but the labels are just not there. What I am doing wrong?

[image: screen_shot_multi_value]

**`fields.py`**

```
from .widgets import OtherSelectorWidget

class OtherModelField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.inner_choices = kwargs.pop('choices', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return OtherFormField(choices=self.inner_choices, **kwargs)


class OtherFormField(MultiValueField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.choices = kwargs.pop('choices')
        self.widget = OtherSelectorWidget(choices=self.choices)
        fields = (CharField(), CharField(),)
        super().__init__(fields=fields, require_all_fields=False, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        return str(data_list)
```

**`widgets.py`**

```
from datetime import date
from django.forms import widgets


class OtherSelectorWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, choices=None, attrs=None):
        self.choices = choices
        _widgets = (
            widgets.RadioSelect(choices=choices),
            widgets.TextInput(attrs=attrs),
        )
        super().__init__(_widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return [value[0], value[1]]
        return [None, None, ]

    def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):

        return ''.join(rendered_widgets)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        datelist = [
            widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i)
            for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]

        radio_data = self.widgets[0].value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_0')
        text_data = self.widgets[1].value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_1')
        try:
            D = [radio_data, text_data]
        except ValueError:
            return ''
        else:
            return D
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be a glitch in Django. Here is a link to a ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29200

I dealt with it by adding `wrap_label` to widget's context:

```
class OtherSelectorWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        con = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        con['wrap_label'] = True
        return con
```

Then everything is rendered properly